# MYSQL Sorting by alternative sets of results by a column

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by, alternate

**Suppose we have the result set something like this by a column_id:**
1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4

**I have already tried Usual "order by asc" and it returned me:**

1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4

**But required result set is:**

1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4

Also Used "group by" function, Since it is used with aggregation functions it returns me just 1st set of results: 1,2,3,4

**Please help me solving this.**

Comment: Which '1' comes first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use user defined variables for the desired result set

```
SELECT column_id
FROM (
SELECT column_id,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = column_id THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END seq,
@g:= column_id
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:= NULL,@r:=0) t
ORDER BY column_id
) t1
ORDER BY seq,column_id
```